# Typescript callback parameter with specific type?

Tags: json, typescript, node.js-fs

I am new to TypeScript and I am trying to understand how to define the callback for a function of which the callback must have a parameter type but i don't know the correct syntax for it.

This is my current function:

```
function LoadJSON(callback: Function(string)) {
    FS.readFile(dir + '/' + file, (err, fd) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(fd);
        console.log('File loaded');
        callback(JSON.stringify(fd));
        return;
    });
}
```

The issue is this line:

```
//'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
function LoadJSON(callback: Function(string))
```

What is the correct syntax ?

I am trying to make it clear the provided callback function must take a string.

Comment: `callback: (str: string) => void`

Comment: Ah thank you ! :) So i presume that the void part means the function has a return type of void ?

Comment: yes, `void` means tat it has nothing to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you are using is invalid in the typescript. What you are looking for has the following pattern:

```
type Func = (argName: argType) => ReturnType
```

I presume you don't have any return type so you can replace `ReturnType` with `void` which represents that function is not returning anything.

```
function LoadJSON(callback: (argName: string) => void) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment and just wanted to extend user wonderflame's `callback: (str: string) => void` answer with the [TypeScript Functions Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html). The docs are very helpful, informative, and will help you understand functions in TypeScript further and give you a further understanding of why the answer is correct.

The site gives the example:

***The syntax `(a: string) => void` means “a function with one parameter, named a, of type string, that doesn’t have a return value”. Just like with function declarations, if a parameter type isn’t specified, it’s implicitly any.***